Create directory with invalid Path leads to strange results depending on drive letter
A bit hard to explain. 
Forgot to add a backslash after the colon while trying to create a directory. Received no error but couldn't find the created folder.
using System.IO;

private static void CreateWrongDirectory()
{
    var falseCPath = @"C:Temp\MyTest";
    var falseDPath = @"D:Temp\MyTest";

    var currentDirectoryD = @"D:\Temp\CurrentDirectory";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDirectoryD);

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectoryD);
    Console.WriteLine($"Working Directory: {Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}");

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to create \"{falseCPath}\"");
    var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(falseCPath);
    Console.WriteLine($"Created \"{di.FullName}\"");
    di.Delete();

    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to create \"{falseDPath}\"");
    di = Directory.CreateDirectory(falseDPath);
    Console.WriteLine($"Created \"{di.FullName}\"");
    di.Delete();

    Console.WriteLine();

    var currentDirectoryC = @"C:\Temp\CurrentDirectory";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(currentDirectoryC);

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectoryC);
    Console.WriteLine($"Working Directory: {Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}");

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to create \"{falseCPath}\"");
    di = Directory.CreateDirectory(falseCPath);
    Console.WriteLine($"Created \"{di.FullName}\"");
    di.Delete();

    Console.WriteLine($"Trying to create \"{falseDPath}\"");
    di = Directory.CreateDirectory(falseDPath);
    Console.WriteLine($"Created \"{di.FullName}\"");
    di.Delete();
}

Output is:
Working Directory: D:\Temp\CurrentDirectory

Trying to create "C:Temp\MyTest"
Created "C:\Temp\MyTest"
Trying to create "D:Temp\MyTest"
Created "D:\Temp\CurrentDirectory\Temp\MyTest"

Working Directory: C:\Temp\CurrentDirectory

Trying to create "C:Temp\MyTest"
Created "C:\Temp\CurrentDirectory\Temp\MyTest"
Trying to create "D:Temp\MyTest"
Created "D:\Temp\MyTest"

How come that depending on the current directory and drive letter a "wrong" path once gets created and the other time not?

This is intended behavior of Windows filepaths. If you lack a directory separator between the drive letter (C:) and the file, it's considered "relative to the drive's working directory". CreateDirectory uses Path.GetFullPath internally which correctly implements this behavior.
If you're trying to access C:Foo with a working directory of C:\cwd, the path is added onto the working directory, creating C:\cwd\Foo. If you're not in C:, like D:\cwd, it's relative to the drive's root, creating C:\Foo. (because C: lacks a current working directory, beacuse you're in D:)

It makes more sense if you think of filepaths as being made of three parts:
[(OPTIONAL) Drive Letter + ":"] + [(OPTIONAL) Root Indicator ("\")] + [File Path]


If there's a drive letter, we switch to it.
If there's a root indicator, we start at the root of the drive. Otherwise, we start at the CWD.

If there is a drive letter, but no root indicator, the user wants this path to be in a certain drive but also relative to the CWD. If we're already in this drive, no problem. If we aren't in this drive, Windows gives up and defaults to the root of the drive.

File path formats on Windows systems - .NET Microsoft Learn even points out that this is a common source of issues:

C:\Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln, C:Projects\apilibrary\apilibrary.sln


Note the difference between the last two paths. Both specify the optional volume specifier (C: in both cases), but the first begins with the root of the specified volume, whereas the second does not. As result, the first is an absolute path from the root directory of drive C:, whereas the second is a relative path from the current directory of drive C:. Use of the second form when the first is intended is a common source of bugs that involve Windows file paths.


Especially this example from the same page shows the exact behavior I experienced.
